# How can I change the step size of QTimeEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtimeedit

`QSpinBox` has a `singleStep` property which determines how much the value changes when the step up/down buttons are pressed. I am looking for an analogous behaviour in `QTimeEdit`

```
auto t = new QTimeEdit ();
t->setDisplayFormat ("m:ss.zzz");
t->setTime ({0,0,1,234});
```

If I press the up/down arrows on this widget, the time changes by 1 minute at a time. I want to step by e.g. 100ms instead.

How?

Comment: The step in a QTimeEdit depends on the part that is selected, for example in your case select the section "234"

Comment: If I select the ms component, it increments by 1ms. Can I make it increment by 100ms?

Comment: okay, what if you select another section should the default step be modified or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the step you must overwrite the [`stepBy()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/qdatetimeedit.html#stepBy) method.

In the next part I change the step to 100ms if the current section is `MSecSection`, in the other sections the default step is maintained:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class TimeEdit: public QTimeEdit
{
public:
    using QTimeEdit::QTimeEdit;
    void stepBy(int steps) override{
        if(currentSection() == MSecSection){
            setTime(time().addMSecs(steps*100));
            return;
        }
        QTimeEdit::stepBy(steps);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TimeEdit t;
    t.setDisplayFormat ("m:ss.zzz");
    t.setTime ({0,0,1,234});
    t.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

---

The next example is if you want the step of 100 ms for any section:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class TimeEdit: public QTimeEdit
{
public:
    using QTimeEdit::QTimeEdit;
    void stepBy(int steps) override{
        setTime(time().addMSecs(steps*100));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TimeEdit t;
    t.setDisplayFormat ("m:ss.zzz");
    t.setTime ({0,0,1,234});
    t.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```